# Library that can do math on float arrays on the GPU?

Tags: c++, math, gpu

I would like to do basic mathematical operations (addition, subtraction, division, multiplication) on large arrays of floats on the GPU, are there any libraries in C++ that can achieve this?

For example, in pseudo-code:

```
A = [1,2,3,...]
B = [2,3,9,...]
C = A+B //[3,5,12,...]
D = A-B //[-1,-1,-6,...]
E = A/B //[0.5,0.6,0.3,...]
F = A*B //[2,6,27,...]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [Boost.Compute](http://boostorg.github.io/compute/) library. It is a C++ STL-like library which allows you to perform many operations on the GPU (or any OpenCL compatible device). Unlike Thrust it is not limited to NVIDIA GPUs.

The source code is here: https://github.com/boostorg/compute

Comment: I was not aware of this library (thanks!) Have you played with it? Any advice?

Comment: @Arrieta: Yeah, I wrote it ;-). It is still under active development but it provides a much more natural C++ interface to OpenCL. If you send me some information about your use-case (via email or otherwise) I can offer more specific advise.

Comment: Hi @KyleLutz, couldn't you be so kind to show in the answer how to implement C = A+B or other custom binary operation using boost::compute? This would be highly helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/example/vector_addition.cpp

Answer (score 4):

[Thrust](https://code.google.com/p/thrust/).

This example is from their site:

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{
    // generate 32M random numbers on the host
    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(32 << 20);
    thrust::generate(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), rand);

    // transfer data to the device
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec = h_vec;

    // sort data on the device (846M keys per second on GeForce GTX 480)
    thrust::sort(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end());

    // transfer data back to host
    thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), h_vec.begin());

    return 0;
}
```

And their [`saxpy` example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/saxpy.cu) is closer to what you asked; look at the fragment:

```
thrust::transform(X.begin(), X.end(), Y.begin(), Y.begin(), saxpy_functor(A));
```

Comment: Looks like a great library, the only problem I can see is that it only works on NVidia cards. Do you know any other libraries similar to Thrust, which are not limited to NVidia cards?

Comment: @user1973386: I am not familiar with any. However, user @KyleLutz has answered that `Boost.Compute` may be an alternative. I will check it out.

Answer (score 4):

[VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl) is another library that could help you.  As of v1.0.0, it has OpenCL and CUDA backends. Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <vexcl/vexcl.hpp>

int main() {
    // Get all compute devices that support double precision.
    vex::Context ctx(vex::Filter::DoublePrecision);

    std::vector<double> a = {1, 2, 3, 4,  5};
    std::vector<double> b = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    // Allocate memory and copy input data to compute devices.
    vex::vector<double> A(ctx, a);
    vex::vector<double> B(ctx, b);

    // Do the computations.
    vex::vector<double> C = A + B;
    vex::vector<double> D = A - B;
    vex::vector<double> E = A / B;
    vex::vector<double> F = A * B;

    // Get the results back to host.
    vex::copy(C, a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL is one such "library" - technically it is not a library, but a language of it's own, based on C99. The OpenCL runtime system will allow you to create threads that run on the GPU (or on the CPU) in multiple threads that each take care of one small part of the calculation, and you can configure how many threads you want to run.